# Unicode string to backslash-encoded non-unicode 7-bit ASCII in python?

Tags: python, string, encoding, utf-8

Environment: **Python 2.6** ... **Python 2.higher-than-6**

I have correct `u''` UTF-8 strings that I need to change into ASCII coded format in standard Python 2.6-ish ASCII strings. Like so:

```
def conversionSolution(utf8StringInput):
{
    ...
    return(asciiStringResult)
}

utf8string = u'\u5f00\u80c3\u83dc'
asciistring = conversionSolution(utf8string)
print asciistring
```

With `...` filled in, the above would print out...

## \u5f00\u80c3\u83dc

and **not**...

## 开胃菜

Let me emphasize that I do *not* want the UTF-8 here; I specifically require 0-127 encoded ASCII backslash data that I can subsequently manipulate strictly as 7-bit ASCII.

Comment: `utf8string` is not actually an UTF-8 string. It is an Unicode string. You could encode it to UTF-8 by calling `.encode('utf-8')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def conversionSolution(utf8StringInput):
    return repr(utf8StringInput)[2:][:-1]

utf8string = u'\u5f00\u80c3\u83dc'
asciistring = conversionSolution(utf8string)
print asciistring
```

Answer (score 1):

You could call `.encode('unicode-escape')` to do this.

That being said, you're talking about manipulating that string afterwards. There is not much useful you can do with that string afterwards. Eg. if you slice it you may slice in the middle of these escape sequences. Case folding of course doesn't work, etc. If you need to manipulate that string you should keep it as an unicode string.

Comment: I'm not manipulating this content in the sense you mean. I'm passing it through 7-bit FEC AFSK encoded RF data channels and it has to get to the endpoint intact so it can be converted back, while being 100% human-readable in the RF pipeline within its 7-bit limits during the transfer. Lesson: don't assume you know the best practice when you don't know the use case.

Comment: @fyngyrz I agree about not guessing the use case, although I wouldn't call this transmitting a string rather than manipulating a string. But we also have to assume other people with different use cases will encounter this question + answer.